# Sonarqube 3.6.1 to 4.3 upgrade fail

Tags: sonarqube

I tried to upgrade my 3.6.1 SonarQube installation to 4.3 and after I "launched"

```
http://xxxxx:9000/setup
```

I got the following error message

> Impossible to upgrade database
>
> Migration failed: org/apache/xml/utils/PrefixResolver . Please check
>   logs.

with the trace :

```
2014.05.06 16:54:48 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
org/apache/xml/utils/PrefixResolver
        org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.CheckRepository.getChecks(CheckRepository.java:34)
        org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.CheckRepository.getCheckClasses(CheckRepository.java:45)
        org.sonar.plugins.xml.rules.XmlRulesRepository.createRules(XmlRulesRepository.java:43)
        org.sonar.server.rule.DeprecatedRulesDefinition.define(DeprecatedRulesDefinition.java:92)
        org.sonar.server.rule.RuleDefinitionsLoader.load(RuleDefinitionsLoader.java:44)
        org.sonar.server.debt.DebtModelBackup.reset(DebtModelBackup.java:159)
        org.sonar.server.startup.RegisterDebtModel.start(RegisterDebtModel.java:44)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
        org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
        org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
        org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
        org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:421)
        org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:46)
        org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTaks(ServerComponents.java:418)
        org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.startLevel4Components(ServerComponents.java:395)
        org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:115)
        org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:80)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
        org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
        org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
        org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
        org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
        org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
        org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
        org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
        org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
        org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
        org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
        org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
        org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
        org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
        org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
        org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
        org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
        org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
        org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
        org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
        org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
        org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
        org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
        org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
        org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTFM :) : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

Several plugins were out of date !